# string Concatenate in yml file and use with aspnetcore 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, yaml

yml string concatenate does not work with .NET applications.I have tried by removing '$' sign, but it is still not working(Java application uses $ sign - Working fine with Java apps). It is working fine for a single value, but not with concatenation.

yml-01
cicd:
  dbname: 172.10.10.110
  port: 5432

yml-02
datasource:
  url: jdbc:postgresql://${cicd:dbname}:${cicd:port}/sample-db

Answer (score 1):

A solution for placeholder resolution in .NET Configuration (similar to that provided by spring) is available in [Steeltoe.Common](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Common). We haven't added `WebHostBuilder` or `IConfigurationBuilder` extensions just yet, but if you add a recent reference to Steeltoe.Common from the [Steeltoe Dev feed](https://www.myget.org/F/steeltoedev/api/v3/index.json) you should be able to do something like this:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder ResolveConfigurationPlaceholders(this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder, LoggerFactory loggerFactory = null)
{
    return hostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
       {
           config.AddInMemoryCollection(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.GetResolvedConfigurationPlaceholders(config.Build(), loggerFactory?.CreateLogger("Steeltoe.Configuration.PropertyPlaceholderHelper")));
     });
}
```

The code above is used in the [Steeltoe fork of eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/eShopOnContainers)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [YamlDotNet](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet).

Here's an example of how to solve your problem using that lib

```
using YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel;
using YamlDotNet.Core;
```

Then in your method

```
var dbname = "172.10.10.110";
var port = "5432";
string content;
using (var reader = new StreamReader("your yml file")) 
{
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

var doc = new StringReader(content);
var yaml = new YamlStream();
yaml.Load(doc);

// Add the url where you use string interpolation to replace the values
var ymlFile = (YamlMappingNode)yaml.Documents[0].RootNode;
ymlFile.Children["datasource"] = new YamlMappingNode
{
    { "url", $"jdbc:postgresql://{dbname}:{port}/sample-db" }
};
yaml.Save(File.CreateText("C:\\yourNewFile.yml"), assignAnchors: false);
```

[Here's](https://www.nuget.org/packages/YamlDotNet.NetCore/1.0.0/) a link to the NetCore package

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by writing an extension method to the IConfiguration interface.

```
    public static string ReadFromConfigRepo(this IConfiguration configuration, string key)
    {
        var pattern = @"\{(.*?)\}";
        var query = configuration[key];

        if (query.Contains('{'))
        {
            var matches = Regex.Matches(query, pattern);
            string value;
            foreach (Match m in matches)
            {
                value = configuration[m.Value.Substring(1, m.Value.Length - 2)];
                query = query.Replace(m.Value, value);
            }
        }
        return query.Trim();
    }
```